# Sharepoint Online - 3 Level Cascading Dropdown - Stops working on addition of 3rd Level

Tags: sharepoint-online, spservices, dropdown, cascading

I've been browsing and looking for tips here on creating a 3 level cascading dropdown on Sharepoint Online (O365 and Sharepoint Designer 2013). I've been able to get a 2 level one working perfectly, but as soon as I add a third level, everything stops working.

Unfortunately there is no error code/pop-up like if I just didn't one of the required parent or children.

Here is where I create the entry:

[image]

So, the Parent and Child in the first section would be "Category" and "Issue", respectively, and in the second section would be "Issue" and "Subissue", respectively.

Category and Issue work fine on their own , but the addition of Subissue and the code to support it just results in everything being available for selection.

The list names are (sorry that I can't post individual images, I'm being limited in links):

Category, Issues, Subissues

I updated seattle.master with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
```

This was inserted under `<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />` on line 29

I then added the following to both NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx, under `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">` on line 72 in each:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns( 
{ 
    relationshipList: "Issues",  //GUID Of The list Your Looking Up your Value In
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Category", //Column Name Your Looking Your Value Up From
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",   //Column Which Contains Data Your Want To Return
    parentColumn: "Category",  //Your Lookup Value For Above
    childColumn: "Issue",  //Where you want to put it in your new list
    debug: true 
}); 

$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns( 
{ 
    relationshipList: "Subissues",  //GUID Of The list Your Looking Up your Value In
    relationshipListParentColumn: "Issues", //Column Name Your Looking Your Value Up From
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",   //Column Which Contains Data Your Want To Return
    relationshipListSortColumn: "ID",
    parentColumn: "Issue",  //Your Lookup Value For Above
    childColumn: "Subissue",  //Where you want to put it in your new list
    debug: true

});

}); 
</script>
```

Again, it works until I add the Subissue to the form. If I don;t add it and try to run the form, it says that Subissue is missing, but when I add it, it gives no errors and just doesn't work.

I hope I've covered all the info that ye need, but if I've missed something, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't showing your second call for the Subissue, but make sure the you are using the right names for the columns, as shown in the [documentation] (http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns).

It could also be an issue with the way you have structured your relationship lists. Again, check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for myself - what worked for me was ensuring that the choice column items for my drop down were not "required". For some reason, the requirement was breaking the drop-down functionality.